# Python-docx and preserving formatting

Tags: python, python-docx

I am trying to automate report writing using python-docx. I denote replacements in my template document inside chevron brackets. e.g. `<customer_name>`.

This works fine by iterating over paragraphs in python, and performing string replacements. The downside is it removes any highlighting that I had applied to non-replacement text. Bold, italic, and underline text appears OK.

```py
for p in doc.paragraphs:
    p.text = p.text.replace('<customer_name>', 'John Smith')
```

I have also tried iterating over runs instead (these are another subset of paragraphs provided by the module) but this is not robust enough, as my tags get divided over multiple runs and my replace statement cannot detect them without difficulty.

Am I overlooking some small detail or alternative method that would allow me to alter the text without removing the highlighting?

Answer (score 1):

By further inspecting the `run` object, there are two attributes of interest: `font` and `element`. The `font` attribute contains an attribute called `text` that can be used to extract and edit the text of different runs. The `element` attribute contains an attribute called `highlight_color`. By setting `highlight_color` to `None`, one can remove highlighting.

A downside is that there is no guarantee that the full tag `<customer_name>` will appear in a single run which means that a series of `if` statements need to be employed to search for the tag over a series of runs.

Comment: Please note: this is an answer to my own question based on trial and error. I am still interested in more elegant solutions to award an answer to.

Comment: You can still join an entire paragraph into a single text, just to check the position of your search string. That will give you an offset – then, process runs and update the offset while you do that. Even if the search string occurs over multiple runs (and it does not *contains* mixed formatting), you can make a single run of it to write back.

Comment: Good idea! I'll give it a go.